# How to display Rating(0-5) column from Posts List under each post of default.aspx page

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have created one Blog site in SharePoint 2010, in which I need to display Rating under each blog post, I had made in-build rating setting functionality, I need to display the "Rating(0-5)" column under each post, In default.aspx page I have added the column but it is not displaying.

Can anyone share idea how to display Rating column from Posts List under each post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create custom copy of the blog.xsl where you add this to the position where you want the ratings to be shown:

```
<!--Start Blog Post Average Rating  -->
<div style="margin-left:5px;">
<xsl:for-each select="$Fields">
<xsl:if test="@Name ='AverageRating'">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="@Name='AverageRating'">
<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="PrintFieldWithDisplayFormLink">
<xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
<xsl:with-param name="Position" select="$Position"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<!--End Blog Post Average Rating   -->
```

Then you reference that XSL in the Posts web part using SharePoint Designer.

More details [here](http://blog.henryong.com/2011/10/28/adding-sharepoint-social-rating-stars-to-the-homepage-of-sharepoint-blog-sites/).